# autoboxing not working in java

Tags: java, autoboxing

I have the following Java class:

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){

        String s = 23.toString();//compilation error is ';' expected
        s = s + "raju";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

but as per auto boxing 23.toString() must convert to new Integer(23).toString() and
 executes that line. So why am I still getting a compilation error?

Comment: Don't use `new Integer(23)`.  Use `Integer.valueOf(23)`. The `Integer` class does some internal caching of low-valued `Integer` instances, so `valueOf` is more efficient.

Comment: What you are attempting to do is casting, NOT auto-boxing. You are asking a compiler to guess which `Object type` you want to cast your original `int` to in order to be able to use `toString()` method. And teh compiler is unable to guess correctly because all objects will have toString() method.

Comment: @GermannArlington Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the corresponding primitive type.
    Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @reddy Sorry, what did you mean by your last comment?

Answer (score 5):

23 is of type int, not Integer. It is a primitive, not an object.

```
Integer.valueOf(23).toString();
```

This is better than using the constructor as the valueOf method will use cache values in the range -128 to 127.

You probably want to refer to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: int will convert to Integer because of auto boxing

Comment: If it not convert int to Integer then what is the use of autoboxing

Comment: Not for the code you have written. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: I got the answer here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 5):

You're confused about when autoboxing is expected to work.  In this case, you're trying to use an Object method on a plain old data type (an int).

Instead, try [Integer.valueof()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29):

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        // String s = 23.toString() will not work since a int POD type does not
        // have a toString() method.
        // Integer.valueOf(23) gets us an Integer Object.  Now we can 
        // call its toString method
        String s=Integer.valueof(23).toString();
        s=s+"raju";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Autoboxing would work if you were passing that int to a method that expected an Integer as a parameter.  For example:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
// Autoboxing will silently create an Integer here and add it to the list
intList.add(23);
// In this example, you've done the work that autoboxing would do for you
intList.add(Integer.valueof(24));
// At this point, the list has two Integers, 
// one equivalent to 23, one equivalent to 24.
```

Comment: Actually, you want `Integer.valueOf(23).toString()`.  `Integer.valueOf(int)` returns an `Integer`, not a `String`.  In this case, `String.valueOf(int)` would work, but that's not what is being illustrated...

Answer (score 3):

`23` is `int` primitive, replace with `new Integer(23)` (wrapper on primitive)

Comment: or `"" + 23`, less chars

Comment: If it not convert int to Integer then what is the use of autoboxing

Answer (score 1):

It is not autoboxing what you are doing. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

This should work:

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Integer i=23;//autoboxing int to Integer
        String s=i.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right that Integer i=23 is technically autoboxing.  However, the caching of valueof is compelling.

Comment: @BobCross: of course, but that wouldn't show the autoboxing, would it?

Comment: Like I said, you're right: that is an example of autoboxing.  It was pretty clear from the question, though, that the OP is confused about at least two things.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote about type type conversion, not autoboxing.

For convert to string you can do next:

```
String s="23";
```

or

```
Integer i = new Integer(23);
s=i.toString()+"raju";
```

Autoboxing is automatical convert primitive `int` to `Integer`:

```
Integer i = 23; //Old variant Integer i = new Integer(23);
int a = i; //Old variant int i = (int) someInteger;
```

Answer (score 0):

It dosen't work because Java will not let you dereference a primitive. Autoboxing works for things like assignment and passing a primitive to a method in place of an object.